# How to fix variable declaration error from dynamic sql in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dynamic-sql

I am trying to get sum of column values for more than 50 columns, so I used dynamic sql where my tables in bigquery. I looked into dynamic sql syntax and came up this solution. My goal is to get sum of columns values in 6 months where I have a lot of columns to do sum.

**my attempt in dynamic sql**

here is my dynamic sql that I tried in bigquery:

```
DECLARE column_list ARRAY<STRING>;
DECLARE query STRING;

SET column_list = [  'prod_ab_amt' ,
  'prod_bf_amt' ,
  'prod_gm_amt' ,
  'catg_cg_amt' ,
  'catg_dh_amt' ,
  'catg_xy_amt' ,
  'catg_mk_amt' ,
  'brand_hk_amt' ,
  'brand_hp_amt' ,
  'brand_vm_amt']

SET query = (
  SELECT CONCAT(
    'SELECT user_id, extract(year from purchase_date) as purch_yr, ',
     ' CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM purchase_date) < 7 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS purch_half_period, ',
    STRING_AGG('SUM(', column, ') AS ', column),
    ' FROM trans',
    ' GROUP BY user_id, purch_yr, purch_half_period'
  )
  FROM UNNEST(column_list) AS column
);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query;
```

but I am getting this error though:

> variable declarations are allowed only at the start of a block or
> script at [13:1]

**update- new error**

based on comment, I put declare variables in the begging, but now I am getting this error:

> Query error: No matching signature for aggregate function STRING_AGG
> for argument types: STRING, STRING, STRING, STRING. Supported
> signatures: STRING_AGG(STRING); STRING_AGG(STRING, STRING);
> STRING_AGG(BYTES); STRING_AGG(BYTES, BYTES)

does anyone know is this really syntax error in this dynamic sql? any thoughts?

**update**

input table and values are simulated. columns of input table also minimally simulated for reproducible purpose. I think using dynamic sql is right way to do but now end up with error. Can anyone point me out how to make this dynamic sql work?

**minimal data**

here is my minimal data that simulated to actual input table: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KoR80cl_).

can anyone suggest how to fix the issues in above dynamic sql? I intend to make this work in bigquery standard sql. any helps would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: the declare must be before the first set, so put it at the start

Comment: @nbk thanks, I put declare variables first, now getting new error, I updated my post with new error, do you have any best guess on this?

Comment: @nbk error is gone but why I am not fetching any data? is it because if `execute immediate query`. How should I write back output as table,like `with tb1 as (my dynamic sql above)`? now it said syntex error on this line: `DECLARE column_list ARRAY<STRING>;`. Do you mind to share your thoughts?

Comment: you run `SELECT
  FORMAT('my query is "%s"',query) AS result;` and see the result of your string, copy it and see what error it throughs.

Comment: it must be ARRAY <STRING> with a space

Comment: @nbk thanks for the help. it is still not clear for me how to print out of dynamic sql above. Could you show what do you mean by that above? I am kinda of new to dynamic sql so why it is not fetched anything even query is correct now. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the aggregation function needs a single string so CONCAT the strings in the `STRING_AGG`

```
 STRING_AGG(CONCAT('SUM(', column, ') AS ', column)),
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Could you show me how should I write output of dynamic sql as table? Could you extend your solutions if possible? this is how I did based on your comment above, but still not sure I am doing right. here is [my attempt](https://dbfiddle.uk/0-3xvnMO). thanks